# identifying hovered point with Flot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

Hopefully this questions isn't too confusing or long, I'm working with the [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) examples, specifically [this one.](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting.html)

I'm using flot to graph some data I've been gathering into a Scatter chart. I'm using the following function to do so...

```
function genScatter(){
    var no = getSelectedRepeat();
    $.get("getPages.json",{rid: no},function(data){
        var d1 = [];
        $.each(data,function(i,obj){
            d1.push([obj.queries,obj.count,{url: obj.url}]);
        })
        $.plot($("#scatter"), [ { label: "Pages",
            data: d1, 
            lines:{show: false},
            points:{show: true}}],{
            xaxis:{min: 1},
            grid:{ hoverable: true}
        });
  });

}
```

My code generates a Scatter chart with various points. When I hover over a point the following listener gets activated...

```
$("#scatter").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
$("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
$("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));
    if (item) {
        if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
            previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

            $("#tooltip").remove();
            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

            /*this would be the line where I extract
             the url and forward it to showToolTip.*/
            showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                        item.series.label  + ": " + y);
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#tooltip").remove();
        previousPoint = null;            
    }

});
```

where `showTooltip` is defined is...

```
function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
   $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y + 5,
        left: x + 5,
        border: '1px solid #fdd',
        padding: '2px',
        'background-color': '#fee',
        opacity: 0.80
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}
```

Basically, when hovering over a point I'd like to render the value for `url` added with the point to `d1` but I haven't been able to because the `item` object doesn't return `url` inside `item.datapoint` only the x,y value of the points are returned. `url` is included inside `item` but under `item.data` in an array with all of the other points in the graph.

My question is, either identifying the point uniquely from the array listed in `item.data` or forcing `flot` to include `url` inside `item.datapoint` is there a way to get the `url` to a corresponding point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you define your data structure like that then you should be able to get the url in your plothover callback with (example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/wnJGx/3/)):

```
item.series.data[item.dataIndex][2].url
```